# Maximum character length for PHP multiline regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to evaluate a multiline RegExp with `preg_match_all`.
Unfortunately there seems to be a character limit around 24,000 characters (24,577 to be specific).
Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Pseudo-code:

```
<?php
$data = 'TRACE: aaaa(24,577 characters)';
preg_match_all('/([A-Z]+): ((?:(?![A-Z]+:).)*)\n/s', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Working example (with < 24,577 characters): https://3v4l.org/8iRCc

Example that's NOT working (with > 24,577 characters): https://3v4l.org/ceKn6

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the regex match all about?

Comment: @nice_dev I need to read a log file which has different information like TIME:, DATE: etc. and TRACE: is a stack trace of the php function that executes it. It can be very long and it seems there is some limit but I cannot find anything about that.

Comment: It looks unlikely to me that PHP will impose any restriction on regex match length.

Comment: @nice_dev Could also be a limit on tries for the regex to match. With a more Performant one (See answer above) it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might rewrite the pattern using a negated character class instead of the tempered greedy token approach with the negative lookahead:

```
([A-Z]+): ([^A-Z\r\n]*(?>(?:\r?\n|[A-Z](?![A-Z]*:))[^A-Z\r\n]*)*)\r?\n
```

- `([A-Z]+):`  Capture **group 1**, match 1+ uppercase chars `:` and a space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^A-Z\r\n]*` Match 1+ times any char except A-Z or a newline
  - `(?>` Atomic group

    - `(?:` Non capture group

      - `\r?\n` Match a newline
      - `|` Or
      - `[A-Z]` Match a char other than A-Z
      - `(?![A-Z]*:)` Negative lookahead, assert not optional chars A-Z and `:`
    - `)` Close non capture group
    - `[^A-Z\r\n]*` Optionally match any char except A-Z
  - `)*` Close atomic group and optionally repeat
- `)\r?\n` Close group 2 and match a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsdibl/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/AT4O6)

If the `TRACE:`  is at the start of the string, you can also add an anchor:

```
^([A-Z]+): ([^A-Z\r\n]*(?>(?:\r?\n|[A-Z](?![A-Z]*:))[^A-Z\r\n]*)*)\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7VNld/1)

**Edit**

If the strings start with the same format, you can capture and match all lines that do not start with the opening format.

```
^([A-Z]+): (.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z]+):`  Capture **group 1**
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with the pattern `[A-Z]+:`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YZ4gAz/1)

In php you can use

```
$re = '/^([A-Z]+): (.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*)/m';
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/5W0fH)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Unfortunately it won't work for my usecase. This is how the log file looks like: https://regex101.com/r/V3Sap5/1 - I need to match all XYZ: with any string coming after that (including new lines etc.) until a new XYZ: comes.

Comment: @Simon Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/1XK4Oa/1 `^([A-Z]+): .*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*`

Comment: Looks great! But unfortunately I cannot get this to work in PHP using preg_match_all. Do you know why? Also I would need a second group to capture the information after the ":"

Comment: @Simon Sure, see https://3v4l.org/5W0fH For the pattern, you only need the multiline flag `/m` like `$re = '/^([A-Z]+): (.*(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]+: ).*)*)/m';`

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm <3 please call yourself the regex master :D If you like to, you can update your answer, I'll accept it now :)

Comment: @Simon I have updated it with an explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233845/discussion-between-simon-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
preg_match('/\A(?>[^\r\n]*(?>\r\n?|\n)){0,4}[^\r\n]*\z/',$data)
```